# Separating one face into two with an edge

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

I am looking to separate the body of the sword into two faces, so that I can easily make the top half black and the bottom silver.

Simply adding an edge in the middle did not separate the blade into two.

I created the edge by directly connecting the vertex at the tip with the vertex near the handle, shown in the picture.

Any tips appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you created the edge with <kbd>F</kbd>? Try using the *Connect Path* tool instead (<kbd>J</kbd>):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to assign two different materials just having separate faces alone will not do the trick

Comment: Thx for the answer, wouldn't the first step be to create 2 faces before changing them into different materials however?

Comment: Yes that is the first step then in edit mode select a face and go to your materials tab and click the plus sign to create a new material and then click assign and go into the nodes and create your material

Comment: How did you create the edge? If you chose the two verticies and pressed F then this would only create a separate edge. Select the two verticies and press J instead.